# Chrome position:fixed and transformZ bug

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transforms, browser-bugs

Take a look at **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CP56H/)** in **FF** and **Chrome**, then remove:

`-webkit-transform:translateZ(0px);`

Fom css, and look again in **Chrome**.

It also makes **Chrome** body container with `min-width:100%`, cutting content (not always).

I need `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0px);` to prevent strange weird black boxes in Chrome appeared cause using transformX + Y for too much elements at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. The problem is that google maps forces GPU compositing on all it's mapping DOM elements via `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`

To fix this issue, you can force GPU compositing on all your *fixed* positioned elements by adding 
`-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to each fixed element

jsfiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/plapier/QA7tK/

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a container with transformZ(); where its child has a position:fixed;

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same issue with a google map inside a fixed parent container. Google maps uses the translateZ property.

I believe it may be related to this bug, which appears to have been fixed in beta builds: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=146894

Comment: Saw, something about such bugs in iframes, during searching the solution for my one.